# why use string constants vs enum constants?

Tags: objective-c, ios, design-patterns

I have a design related question.

I've seen that the UIApplication class has this kind of flags:

```
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification;
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification;
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification;
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification;
```

and, on the other side, the class UITableView declares structs like:

```
typedef enum {
    UITableViewScrollPositionNone,        
    UITableViewScrollPositionTop,    
    UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle,   
    UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
} UITableViewScrollPosition;
```

One is for notifications an the other defines types of objects. I believe that those two are design choices to 'tag' some related objects and make decitions at runtime based on that flag.

Let's say that I want to create a factory of objects that need to be tagged. 
In the image bellow, I want enumerations or ID's for every section and widget. How would any widget communicate or 'invoke' another one?
e.j. [[Containter sharedInstance] presentWidget:?? forSection: ?? withInfo:(id)info];

[image]

Is there a deeper or more accurate reason to choose one of them?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: note that the first will be a 'collection' of strings, where the second will be a selection of integers (starting @ 0)

Comment: Along with what Kevin said, I don't believe you can make an enum of strings.  Enums are great for grouping tags.  At my company we usually explicitly set enum values in case we decide to remove an enum value down the road.  Some code that persists state may use the enum value to indicate the state, however if you load a new version of the app and a value was removed this will effect all the values in the enum unless they are explicitly specified.

Comment: One thing that comes to my mind is that, with strings, you don't have to know the interface of the object that will receive these string. With enums, every object involved would know the receivers interface... am I right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An enum declaration is *not* a struct, the syntax is similar but it simply defines a series of named numbers.

These constants refer to two different kinds of data types, string vs numeric.

The named constants in UIApplications are pointers to NSString *objects*, they have a pointer value and there is also a string constant that they point to (which is in the .m file).  Sort of like declaring some string constants like this (except they are extern and the definition is completed elsewhere):

```
NSString* const UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification = @"UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification";
```

The named constants in UITableViewScrollPosition are names given to *integer* values.  Sort of like:

```
const int UITableViewScrollPositionNone = 0;
```

The reason for using an enum (named numbers) in one case is that they are defining all the possible values vs the string constant they define a few of the values but it is possible for users to define others.  With string constants different libraries could each define their own without any chance of duplicate string addresses, whereas defining extensions to enumerations could have collisions between different libraries if they defined the same integer value to have different meanings.

Comment: You can make a similar argument for the switch from FourCharCodes (OSType and such) to UTIs: you can tag some data as `"com.bigco.document"` without much concern that someone else is using that identifier already, but finding four Mac OS Roman characters that no-one else has claimed (`'BgCo'`?) is a lot harder. You could broaden the number's range to allow more characters, but there's still an artificial upper bound that isn't present when using string identifiers.

Comment: Right.  You would get a linker error if you define two string constants with the same identifier name, you can't have duplicate extern identifiers.  Similarly you can't have duplicate reverse domain name, assuming they are real, registered domains.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you need an enum property on the object. so object.UITableViewScrollPosition

if you declare constants in your class you won't be able to change those for a particular object.